# function not called in addEventListeners

Tags: javascript

Why increaseScore function is not call when click occurred ? My intention is : when the user click on the button , the increaseScore funcion will be called with parameters.

```js
Player = {
  score: 0
};

var Player1 = new Object();
var Player2 = new Object();

var p1 = document.getElementById("Player1"); //p1 = <p>
var p2 = document.getElementById("Player2"); //p2= <p>

button1.addEventListener("click", increaseScore(Player1, p1));

button2.addEventListener("click", increaseScore(Player2, p2));

function increaseScore(PlayerM, p) {


  if (PlayerM.score <= max) {
    PlayerM.score++;
    p.textContent = PlayerM.score;
  }

};
```

Comment: add HTML as well, current snippet is not executable

Comment: The second argument to the `.addEventListener` is just a function's name. If that function has arguments, you have to look at what @Ivar suggested.